# jQuery - If div height is greater than specified height add html after div, but if it is less than specified height don't add

Tags: html, jquery

So, I'm trying to use jQuery to add html after a div (.class-2) if the height of another div (.class-3) is greater than a specified height in jQuery. But if a div's height is less than the specified height in jQuery it should not add the html.

I have included an example of what I have managed to accomplish so far. However, the code was working in Firefox (local version) but not in codepen or in snippet. So, I'm not sure if this is correct either?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  if ($(".class-3").height() > 85) {
    $(".class-2").after("<button class='btnstyle'>Button</button>");
  }
  
});
```

```css
.class-3 {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="class-1">
  <p><b>This divs height is more than 85px</b></p>
  <div class="class-2">
    <div class="class-3">
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class-1">
  <p><b>This divs height is less than 85px</b></p>
  <div class="class-2">
    <div class="class-3">
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class-1">
  <p><b>This divs height is more than 85px</b></p>
  <div class="class-2">
    <div class="class-3">
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As I'm learning jquery this is what I came up with after much trial and error. However, I cannot get the second event of "if div is less than 85 don't add html" to work.

This is because my understanding of jQuery is not great and I'm still learning so I don't understand how.

I have tried searching on Stackoverflow and internet but no luck and trying by myself has also not yielded any working results.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also I have added a link to the pen with the same code here: https://codepen.io/DeltaZero99/pen/oNYPowJ

UPDATE: Fixed typo error with class naming and pen was updated with new jQuery code from provided answer.

Comment: It’s been a long time since I’ve used jQuery, but wouldn’t `$(".class-3")` return an array, not a single element? So you’d need `$(".class-3")[0]` to get the actual element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **$(". Class-3")** you get the list of ALL the elements with that class and, as you can imagine, each of them will have a different otherness.

So you have to browse each single element with jQuery's each function or any other loop, such as FOR loop .. :)

```js
$(function(){
  $(".class-3").each(function(){ // Analyze all the items found 
  if ($(this).height() > 85) { // Check if the element height is greater than 85 
    $(this).parents(".class2") // I am looking for the parent element class-2 
        .after("<button class='btnstyle'>Button</button>"); // I add the HTML code 
  }
  }); 
});
```

```css
.class1 {
    background: #ffe4e4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.class-3 {
    background: #e1fff4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <p><b>This divs height is more than 85px</b></p>
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class-3">
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <p><b>This divs height is less than 85px</b></p>
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class-3">
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <p><b>This divs height is more than 85px</b></p>
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class-3">
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
      Lorem ipsum<br/><br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer works and feel like I've learnt a lot more. Sorry about the typo with class names (class2), didn't spot that when reading over code.